# Declaring < 10 after an integer?

Tags: c++

I didn't want to make a thread about this because it seems so insignificant, but I couldn't find an explanation of this syntax anywhere:

```
int relStack=table->getStack(getAIPlayer())/double(table->getCostToCall())<10;
```

It seems contradictory to me to declare an integer and then state "<10"? The program this is from isn't currently functional, so I can't run it to test this or anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably code written by an old timer who was used to the days when the only way to represent a boolean value was with an `int`. But you'd be better off asking them than posting a question here, honestly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The / operator gets evaluated first, then the < operator will be evaluated. So the answer is 1 or 0 depending on whether division produces a result less than 10 or not.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax could be perfectly fine is that's what they are trying to do. But they could have chosen a **bool**, instead of **int** of course.

Because what the code does is: **relstack** either will be set to **1** (**true**) if the result of (a / b) is lower than 10, or **0** **(false)** otherwise.

later in the code which you have not shown... there could be something like

```
if (relStack)
    cout << "do this";
else 
    cout << "do smt else";
```

Comment: Ahh, I see, I didn't expect int to be able to store true/false values; this makes sense now, thanks.

Comment: One thing you could have mentioned is _why_ this hasn't been implemented with an _if-statement_ or ternary operator.  The answer is most likely to get around branch prediction.